# How to change a theme in MVC4

Tags: themes, asp.net-mvc-4

It seemed like I can download jquery theme I like from jquery site to create new theme. But that does not change much in my MVC site. Can anybody tell me how I can change theme in MVC4 application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand your question:

**How can I replace the base theme in a MVC4 application with a custom generated theme from the jquery ui theme roller?**

My steps for my razor MVC4 visual studio 2012 application created from some MS standard template for intranet application. jQueryUI already was installed in my application with the base theme from nuget.

1. Created the theme using http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and downloaded the zip to some temp folder
2. Extracted the jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js into my Scripts folder
3. Edited my RegisterBundles method in the file App_Start/Bundle.Config
   <strike>`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.js"));`</strike>
   `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"));`
4. Extracted the css subfolder named for my custom theme (e.g. my-theme) into the themes folder "Content/themes/my-theme".
5. Comment out the base theme lines in App_Start BundleConfig.cs and replaced the big base theme StyleBundle with the single-file bundle
   `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/my-theme/css").Include(
               "~/Content/themes/my-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"));`
   <strike>`//bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
           //  "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
           //  "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
           //  ...`</strike>
6. Finally replaced the base-theme bundle call in my layout.cshtml with the new one.
   `@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/kjr-theme/css")`
   <strike>`@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")`</strike>

If there is a better or cleaner way to replace the theme in MVC4 applications, please let me know!

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Since jquery ui version was changed, jquery ui scripts in MVC4 template seem to be not compatible with current version of jquery ui. So you can't just copy css directory of downloaded jquery ui to your theme folder of MVC4, and expect it would be applied for your site.

So what I did was to replace jquery.ui.theme.css with corresponding part in jquery.ui.custom.css. And new theme was correctly shown in my MVC4 site now.

Answer (score 0):

Code Project site uses an implementation of [Chris Pietschmann](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/03/ASPNET-MVC-Implement-Theme-Folders-using-a-Custom-ViewEngine)

Code Project:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32847/ASP-NET-MVC-Dynamic-Themes